# How to make sticky articles show up first in a list of articles?

Tags: views, 6

I have a view showing a list of articles, sorted by date. I tried enabling the *sticky article* option in the publishing options. This made an article I had jump to the top of the list, but then a new article I added pushed the sticky article to second place.

I want a sticky article (pinned) to be first in the list even if I add new articles.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [Drupal 6 is no longer supported](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol). You should upgrade to 7 soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable of the "sticky" option within publishing options (for 1 or more nodes) is only part of the solution: within the "Sort criteria" of your view, you also have to add  "***Node: Sticky***" as your primary sort criterium (using the Views UI).

When adding this sort criterium to your view, you'll also see "*...To list sticky nodes first, set this to descending.*" (which is what you seem to be looking for).